# Get same field from different objects

Tags: java, generics

I want to do a generic method in Java that receives an object and get the same property no matter the type of object it is.

For instance: I have two objects, `car` and `house` and know that these objects have the attribute **id**.
Can I write a such method ?

```
public void method(Object x) {
  x.getId();
}
```

Comment: You could achieve that with an Interface or an Abstract class.

Comment: You _really, really, really_ should be using an interface for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this unless a use of reflection, which is pretty exception-prone.

```
public void method(Object o) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
  Field idField = o.getClass().getDeclaredField("id");
  int id = idField.getInt(o);
}
```

But the common way to solve such operation is using polymorphism or generic method with an interface.

```
public interface Identifiable {
  public int getId();
}

public <T extends Identifiable> void method(T anIdentifiableObject) {
  anIdentifiableObject.getId();
} 

public void method(Identifiable anIdentifiableObject) {
  anIdentifiableObject.getId();
}
```